# OpenRefine Regex and GREL match error

Tags: regex, openrefine

Inside `openRefine` I want to run the below regex on a website's source that finds email addresses with a `mailto` link. My trouble is when running value.match, I get this error:

> Parsing error at offset 12: Bad regular expression (Unclosed character class near index 10 .*mailto:[^ ^)

I have tested the expression in another environment without value.match and it works.

```
value.match(/.*mailto:[^/"/']*.com.*/)
```

Comment: normally they backslash to get a literal. But your regex has 2 unslashed forward slashes. And in that match() the `/` are use to start and end the regex so they have special meaning. I assume it should be `value.match(/.*mailto:[^\"\']*.com.*/)` instead.

Comment: Thanks that cleared up the error but for some reason it is posing null. Any thoughts? I know i have the email with a mailto link in there.

Comment: Showing that mailto link can at least give an idea if it should be a match. Or maybe adding a capture group helps? `isNotNull(value.match(/.*(mailto:[^\"\']*?\.com).*/))`

Comment: As suggested by @LukStorms the OR 'match' function requires one or more capture groups to give you outputs. Once you add capture groups, the output of 'match' will be an array of the capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
isNotNull(value.match(/.*mailto:[^\"\']*.com.*/))
```

as described on our Reference page for the match() function, it return an array of capture groups in your RegEx pattern and then isNotNull() outputs True or False if your value is like that pattern:
https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions#matchstring-s-regexp-p

also described here: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Understanding-Regular-Expressions#basic-examples

You can also use get() as described here in Recipes on our wiki, BUT will only work well if you have only 1 email address per cell (its because the get() function without number from or to, makes assumptions and uses the length of the array to determine the last element and pushes out only the last element, not the first, or third, etc.):
https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Recipes#find-a-sub-pattern-that-exists-at-the-end-of-a-string

For example:

```
get(value.match(/.*(mailto:[^\"\']*.com).*/),0)
```

Comment: This returns false. Is there any way to modify it so the regex returns the value = mailto:example@example.com??

Comment: I don't think it is correct that match() returns True or False. If it matches it returns an array (which can be empty). Otherwise it returns null.

Comment: I've edited and rephrased to be a bit more clear.  Owen is correct that it outputs an array that can be further inspected, which was my point about True or False being output if isNotNull() is used...or the get() wrapping method described further in that link.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have text like:

```
Blah blah <a href="mailto:j.bloggs@example.com">mail me</a>
```

To extract the email address using the match function in OpenRefine you need to use:

```
value.match(/.*mailto:([^\"\']*.com).*/)
```

This will give an array containing the email address, which is captured using a capture group. To extract the email address from the array (which is necessary if you want to store the mail address in an OpenRefine cell) you need to get the string value from the array. e.g.:

```
value.match(/.*mailto:([^\"\']*.com).*/)[0]
```

The difference between your original expression and this one is that the characters are escaped correctly and there is a capture group - basically implementing the advice from @LukStorms in the comments above.